# Kofax Export Connector - check for attached components

Tags: c#, kofax

I have a webservice that publishes the scanned Kofax documents to another application.

This application webservice takes the following data:

- the document (binary)
- the IDs of meta fields (from the application) and their values (the index fields from Kofax)

When creating a mapping for the meta fields I would store the selected index field with the meta field ID to the `releaseSetupData` custom properties.

```
releaseSetupData.CustomProperties.Add("MetaFieldID", "IndexFieldValue");
```

When publishing the scanned document I want to publish a PDF file when the **PDF Generator** is attached otherwise a multipage TIFF file.

How can I check if this generator is attached to the batch class?

As far as I know the TIFF files from Kofax are single pages so I would have to setup a workaround by code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tldr:**
To answer your first question: While I am not sure whether the export connector has access to the queues of the relevant, just use the PDF whenever one is available, and TIFFs otherwise.

I'd check if if a file exists using `DocumentData.KofaxPDFPath` as path. If that is the case, upload a PDF. If no file exists, I'd save the images to a temporary folder using `DocumentData.ImageFiles.Copy()`. In both cases you may want to use `File.ReadAllBytes()`, depending on how your web service call handles said attachments.

Second question: just use 0 for the `ImageType` as the second argument to `DocumentData.ImageFiles.Copy()`.

**More detailed explanation:**

Unfortunately, Kofax's object model is a bit messy, here's how PDFs are handled:

1. The property `DocumentData.KofaxPDFFileName` will contain a full/absolute path to the converted PDF file, if available. This usually points to a file contained in subfolders in the server file share (i.e. CaptureSV\Images)
2. The method `DocumentData.CopyKofaxPDFFile()` will allow you to copy aforementioned file to the path `DocumentData.KofaxPDFPath`, if defined during setup.

It's a bit of a different story for images:

1. Images are exposed as a collection of `ImageFile` in `DocumentData.ImageFiles`. However, as you already mentioned - these are mostly single page TIFFs.
2. `DocumentData.ImageFiles.Copy()` will either allow you to copy all images to the path as defined during setup, i.e. `DocumentData.ImageFilePath` - alternatively, you can provide a string argument with any custom path. Further, it allows you to define an `ImageType`, and 0 means Multipage TIFFs, CCITT Group 4 (please refer to the API Reference for further details).